# How do I switch from 11.10 back to 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, 11.10

O.O. is giving me problems.  I want to switch back to Maverick Meerkat.  Should I use my DVD from a year ago or will there be fewer problems if I download it now and make an new DVD.  I guess I think a newer version of Maverick might have fewer problems than last year's disk of Maverick.  Of course, if they freeze it and never update drivers, etcetera, then I guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same media to install it probably, nothing is normally changed (I think nothing for sure) after the media is released, all bug fixes, security, drivers will come when you do a `apt-get upgrade` so dont worry.

Answer (score 1):

There is no newer version of maverick. Only LTSes get minor releases like that.